# static horizontal nav bar with css - margin issues between IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a static navbar with 4 `<li>` elements, which is supposed to show the user where he/she stands in his progress on the site.
The width of each element is predefined to fit into the page. Now when I display that site, it stretches from left to right on IE but cuts short 10ish pixels on Chrome.

I am looking for a smoother way to get this consistent over IE/FF/Chrome.
Kind regards

CSS:

```
ul#progress {
  list-style:none;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  padding:0px;
  height: auto;
  display: table;
  float:left;
}
ul#progress li {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:table-cell;
  padding-left:9px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
* ul#progress li {
  list-style-type:none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px; 
  padding-top: 5px;
} 
ul#progress li.selected {
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color:#FF8040!important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li id="li_pers" runat="server" style="width:176px"><span class="nav">1. some text</span></li>
<li id="li_bew" runat="server" style="width:176px"><span class="nav">2. more text</span></li>
<li id="li_anl" runat="server" style="width:176px"><span class="nav">3. and more</span></li>
<li id="li_ueb" runat="server" style="width:262px"><span class="nav">4. and somewhat more because of long words</span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

Here's my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/hHTSw/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="progress">
  <li id="li_pers" runat="server"><span class="nav">1. some text</span></li>
  <li id="li_bew" runat="server"><span class="nav">2. more text</span></li>
  <li id="li_anl" runat="server"><span class="nav">3. and more</span></li>
  <li id="li_ueb" runat="server"><span class="nav">4. and somewhat more because of long words</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul#progress {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  width: 790px;
}

ul#progress li {
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 20px; 
  padding: 5px 0 5px 9px;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  width: 176px;
}

ul#progress li#li_ueb {
  width: 262px;
}

ul#progress li.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FF8040!important;
}
```